# Проблемы с кодировкой node.js | samp-node-lib

Tags: javascript, node.js

недавно узнал о такой штуке как [samp-node-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/samp-node-lib) и решил попробовать, задав один вопрос на stackoverflow мне помогли, это радует. Сейчас решил не много попробовать попользоваться данной технологией, но появилась проблема с кодировкой, я допустим напишу `player.SendClientMessage('rgb(250,250,250)', 'Привет, всем')`, мне в коде покажет что всё ок, а на деле мне выведет [image: что-то такое] что-то такое. Я попробовал тоже самое в родном языке для этой игры ***pawno*** и там мне показало это [image: введите сюда описание изображения] всё было нормально, и я честно говоря не знаю как исправить данную проблему. Пробовал изменять кодировки, но ничего не получалось. С английским языком таких проблем нет. Спасибо за внимание, буду рад узнать решение.

Comment: Надо просто перекодировать файл скрипта из кодировки UTF-8 в какую-то однобайтовую: cp1251 или ещё какую...

Comment: ANSI, https://github.com/AmyrAhmady/samp-node/issues/2

Comment: Пробовал перекодировать в cp1251, ситуация особо не поменялась, разве что символы другие теперь показывает.

Comment: Ещё актуально..

Comment: Владислав, а что вам покажет игра, если в неё передать `ЊP…`, `ЊPN`?

Comment: Показывает уже другие символы.

Comment: смотрите, http://pawn-wiki.ru/index.php?/topic/33281-russkii-tekst-v-textdraw-dlja-4-russikov/ тут есть функция `stock Rus(playerid, string[])`, думаю, что творческий перевод её на ваш язык программирования даст то, что вы хотите

Answer (score 0):

UPD: Проблему можно решить с помощью iconv-lite

Как правильно заметил @nörbörnën, здесь проблема на стороне плагина, без его правки не исправить - конвертировать из UTF-8 в ANSI и обратно нужно на его стороне (что и описано в том issue к плагину https://github.com/AmyrAhmady/samp-node/issues/2).

Comment: я не согласен с итоговым "Так что пока эта проблема нерешаема на стороне скрипта"

Comment: Я понял, спасибо за ответ. Буду пытаться достучаться до разработчика скрипта.

Comment: Обновил ответ: можно попробовать решить проблему с помощью пакета iconv-lite. В комментариях того же issue по ссылке можно найти пример